# Como fazer um #if com comparação de duas variaveis usando handlebars e nodejs

Tags: node.js, if, handlebars.js

Meu problema é na criação do #if com uma comparação com duas variaveis na pagina .handlebars. Na pagina de edição recupero os dados e preencho os campos, no entanto no meu select, preciso comparar o id atual com os ids da lista do select, para desabilitar e marcar como selecionado o option que contem a categoria do post atual que estou editando mas essa comparaçao parece nao ser permita desta forma.

```
<select name="categoria" id="categoria" class="form-select">
        {{#each categorias}}
                    
             //esse if nao funciona
             {{#if _id == postagem.categoria._id}}
                    <option value="{{postagem.categoria._id}}" selected="true" disabled>
             {{else}}
                    <option value="{{_id}}">{{nome}}</option>
             {{/if}}
        {{else}}
             <option value="0">Nenhuma categoria</option>
        {{/each}}
</select>
```

Esse é o resultado que quero
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: amigo, conseguiu fazer o que precisava, usando a minha resposta? Se precisar de mais alguma coisa, comente! Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: continua o problema ```Error: Parse error on line 24:
...         {{#if _id == postagem.categoria
-----------------------^
Expecting 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'ID', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'EQUALS'```

Comment: Ué continua o problema porque vc não mudou o código! Vc precisa criar um helper e usá-lo! Vc entendeu para que servem os helpers do handlebars?

Comment: Criei o helper ```ifCompare: function (a, b, options) {if (a == b) { return options.fn(this); } return options.inverse(this);}```  Aparentemente está funcionando bem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Registre o helper que você precisa e utilize ele.
Aqui um exemplo de vários helpers que eu tenho.

```
var register = function(Handlebars) {
    var helpers = {
        isSinglePrice: function(arr, options) {
            if(arr.length === 1) {
                return options.fn(this);
            }else{
                return options.inverse(this);
            }
        },
        choosePriceIcon: function(position){
            if(position === 0){
                return "person";
            }else if(position === 1){
                return "group";
            }else if(position === 2){
                return "groups";
            }
        },
        numberFormat: function (value, options) {
            // Helper parameters
            var dl = options.hash['decimalLength'] || 2;
            var ts = options.hash['thousandsSep'] || ',';
            var ds = options.hash['decimalSep'] || '.';

            // Parse to float
            var value = parseFloat(value);

            // The regex
            var re = '\\d(?=(\\d{3})+' + (dl > 0 ? '\\D' : '$') + ')';

            // Formats the number with the decimals
            var num = value.toFixed(Math.max(0, ~~dl));

            // Returns the formatted number
            return (ds ? num.replace('.', ds) : num).replace(new RegExp(re, 'g'), '$&' + ts);
        }
    };

    if (Handlebars && typeof Handlebars.registerHelper === "function") {
        for (var prop in helpers) {
            Handlebars.registerHelper(prop, helpers[prop]);
        }
    } else {
        return helpers;
    }

};

module.exports.register = register;
module.exports.helpers = register(null);
```

Basta vc criar quantos métodos de helper precisar para fazer as comparações que necessitar e usar isso da forma como achar melhor.

E aqui como você utiliza:

```
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

var handlebars = exphbs.create({
    layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, "views/layouts"),
    partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, "views/partials"),
    defaultLayout: 'index',
    extname: 'hbs',
    helpers: require("./helpers/hbs.js").helpers
});
```

EDIT: Aqui é um exemplo de como você atribuir o Engine do handlebars, com os helpers registrados acima:

```
const app = express();
app.engine('hbs', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', './views')
```

Agora é com você. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Sem esse helper o express é informado sobre o handlebars desta forma ```app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({defaultLayout: 'main'}));```. Como dizer para o express usar o handlebars nesse caso?

Comment: @BernardoLopes acrescentei como você deve fazer para o seu app express utilizar. Fique atento com a questão dos layouts, se não informar o diretório certinho, por exemplo: views/layouts e views/partials não vai funcionar correto o Engine.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função compare no lugar do if!

```js
{{#compare _id '==' postagem.categoria._id}}
    Verdadeiro
  {{else}}
    Falso
{{/compare}}
```